# Prove $G$ is a group under $\ast$ given as $(a, b)*(c, d) = (ac,bc+d)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G = \{(a, b) \text{ }|\text{ } a, b \in \mathbb{R}, a \neq 0 \}$. Let $*$ be an operation on $G$ defined by $$(a, b)*(c, d) = (ac,bc+d)$$ Prove $G$ is a group.

Is this a group or not? because the commutative property does not hold: $$(a,b)*(c,d) = (ac,bc+d) \quad \text{  but }\quad (c,d)*(a,b) = (ca,da+b)$$

Comment: *Abelian* groups must be commutative, while arbitrary groups may not be commutative. With this in mind, have you verified the defining properties of a group hold for $G$?

Comment: What is "a be R a $\neq 0$"?

Comment: Similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924175/is-this-binary-operation-a-group

Answer (score 5):

A **group** is a pair $(G, \ast)$, where $G$ is a set and $\ast$ is a binary operation on $G$, satisfying three properties:

- $\ast$ is associative (i.e. $(g \ast h)\ast k = g\ast(h\ast k)$ for all $g, h, k \in G$),
- there is $e \in G$ such that $e\ast g = g\ast e = g$ for all $g \in G$,
- for every $g \in G$, there is $g^{-1} \in G$ such that $g\ast g^{-1} = g^{-1}\ast g = e$.

If in addition, $\ast$ is commutative (i.e. $g\ast h = h\ast g$ for every $g, h \in G$), then $(G, \ast)$ is called an **abelian group**.

What you have deduced is that $(G, \ast)$ is not an abelian group, but it may still be a group (you need to check the three properties above to see if it is).

Comment: Thanks that has slipped my mind. what would the identity be though because I'm getting (a,b)*(e,e)=(a,b) => (ae,be+e)=(a,b) => (a,b+1)=(a,b) i.e the identity should be (e,0) ?

Comment: Yes, but what number should $e$ be? Also, is $(e, 0)$ a left inverse as well as a right inverse?

Comment: e should be 1 but I know this by inspection. I don't know how to compute that it should be 1

Comment: Doesn't the **closure property** of a group need to be considered as well?

Comment: You should look at what is required to do nothing. What c is required for ac=a for all a and what c and d are required for bc+d=B for all b?

Comment: Remember: identities leave everything unchanged. You should also check that eg=ge=g for all g once you have what you think might be an inverse to "officially" confirm it

Comment: @Glacier: As $\ast$ is a binary operation on $G$, we have $\ast : G\times G \to G$ by definition.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check closure: make sure you maintain a isn't zero! Check that for all sets of valid numbers you can apply the given multiplication to get another valid set.

Identity: see above comments.

Inverses: once you have found the identity as discussed above try to find an element for each g in G that will multiply with g to give your identity. Confirm this is in G and confirm it's a two sided inverse.

If you need help with any step then comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth mentioning that this operation has a name and can be generalized. The operation is called the *semi-direct product* and the group you have formed is $(\mathbb{R}^*,\times)\ltimes (\mathbb{R},+)$. Here, by $(\mathbb{R}^*,\times)$ I mean the group of nonzero real numbers with multiplication as the operation and by $(\mathbb{R},+)$ I mean the real numbers with addition as the operation.

This construction arises naturally when looking at extensions of groups. Let $G$ be a group (not necessarily abelian) and call an extension of $G$ by $N$ the short exact sequence of groups $$0\longrightarrow N \longrightarrow E \longrightarrow G \longrightarrow 1 .$$
Classifying these extensions amounts to finding ways of constructing an $E$ with $N$ as a normal subgroup and $E/N\cong G$. A solution to this problem of finding an $E$ is $N \rtimes G$ where the symbol indicates that $G$ acts on $N$. If this interests you, I recommend Kenneth Brown's *Group Cohomology*. It is accessible after some courses in abstract algebra and perhaps a course in algebraic topology.

Comment: The name is "affine group". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group